# generic Data fetcher

Tags: c#

I'd like to know a way to assign any query result to a generic List based on the mapping between column names and object's property names.

public List getData(string sql, Type object_type)

for example, I have the following sql and an object:

Select name, address, phone
from '''
where ...

Class Person
{
    string name;
    string address;
    string phone;
}

public List getData(string sql, Type type)
  {   ... }

Answer (score 1):

There are packages that already do this -- it's called object-relational mapping.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping

NHibernate is a popular one.